# Computing $a$ and $b$ from $a+b$ and $ab \bmod N$, where factorization of $N$ is unknown

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I have
$$\{a+b, a^2+b^2 \bmod N, a^3+b^3 \bmod N,\ldots\}$$
and
$$\{ab \bmod N, a^p b^q \bmod N, a^{p^2}b^{q^2} \bmod N, a^{p^3} b^{q^3} \bmod N,\ldots\}$$
The factorization of $N=(2p+1)(2q+1)$ is unknown. $p$ and $q$ are unknown too. $i \in \{1,2,...\}$ is a set of positive integers.

Can I compute any thing like $a^i \bmod N$, $b^i \bmod N$, $a^{p^i} \bmod N$ **OR**  $b^{q^i} \bmod N$ for any integer $i$? Just one of them is enough for me.

Comment: Please clarify (a) if $N=pq$ or not. (b) if "Can I compute $a^i \bmod N$ for any integer $i$" means (b1) "Is there some integer $i\ne0$ such that I can compute $a^i \bmod N$", or (b2) "is there some way that for all integer $i$, I can compute $a^i \bmod N$".

Comment: Is the value of $N$ known?

Comment: The value of N is known.

Comment: What is $i$? (b1) and (b2) are false? Please Add all the usefull information in your question (with Edit) and not in the comments.

Comment: (b1) and (b2) is what i want to compute.

Comment: The added $N=(2p+1)(2q+1)$ was badly missing!